# How do you aquire COM uuids for the MMDeviceAPI in C?

Tags: c, winapi, com

I was exploring the MMDeviceAPI in my C program and encountered an issue with the uuids required for `CoCreateInstance`, the linker can't find them.

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator
```

I'm using MSVC and Visual Studio.
And this is the code:

```
#include <Mmdeviceapi.h>

#define __uuidof(Type) &IID_##Type

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

IMMDeviceEnumerator* DeviceEnumerator;

    HRESULT Result = CoCreateInstance(
        &CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator, NULL,
        CLSCTX_ALL, __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator),
        &DeviceEnumerator);
}
```

Both `CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator` and `IMMDeviceEnumerator`'s uuid are defined as external in *Mmdeviceapi.h* so the error makes sense, but I don't understand from where I am supposed to get them. I've been pondering trying to generate them myself with the interface id in the header,  but it feels like I'm working around the problem then.

As far as I understand this, with C++ the __uuidof operator generates the uuids with compiler extensions but in C this is not the case and I have to link to a library containing the uuids (I've done that with DirectX before) or somehow find out how to re-generate them with the interface ID in the header.

Anyone knows the 'right way' to find/aquire the uuids?

**TL;DR**: My linker can't find the UUIDs for MMDeviceAPI and I don't know how to get them.

Comment: There is no right way, this api has a pretty hard assumption that nobody is going to be courageous enough to use it from C.  You should take that assumption serious.  You could limp along by calling CLSIDFromString and IIDFromString, passing the guids you find in the .h file.  Do consider taking advantage of the ability to mix C and C++ code in one project, just declare your helper C++ function as extern "C" so it can link with your C code.

Comment: if use only *C* you can implement it yourself - in some (single) *c* file write `const CLSID CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator = { 0xBCDE0395, 0xE52F, 0x467C, {0x8E, 0x3D, 0xC4, 0x57, 0x92, 0x91, 0x69, 0x2E }};` but of course better use mix *c* and *c++*

Comment: @RbMm I tried doing that, however it appears that there's some element of randomness to the ID's?

Comment: no, here not any randomness. the `const CLSID CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator = { 0xBCDE0395, 0xE52F, 0x467C, {0x8E, 0x3D, 0xC4, 0x57, 0x92, 0x91, 0x69, 0x2E }};` exact match `__uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator)`

Comment: also write in any single your *c* file - `const IID IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator = { 0xA95664D2, 0x9614, 0x4F35, {0xA7, 0x46, 0xDE, 0x8D, 0xB6, 0x36, 0x17, 0xE6 }};` and this will be `(IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator==__uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator))` - so declaration in `<mmdeviceapi.h>` + implementation in some your *.c* file will be work well, however more simply when using *c++*

Comment: @RbMm You're right, I must've done something weird. It's working perfectly now. Looking again at this, it seems that the IID's are just split from the data that the classes are tagged with, for example "BCDE0395-E52F-467C-8E3D-C4579291692E" Can you add that as an answer so that I can use it as the accepted one? :)

Comment: @HansPassant I'm using pure C as a learning experience, so mixing defeats the purpose a bit, the FromString seems like a good solution but since it appears that the API will fail if the ID's are invalid I'll just go with the 'hack' it in with static arrays solution since generally any invalid HRESULT makes the app exit with an MessageBox error.

Comment: this is standard how uuids is converted from registry format to  `struct GUID`. run for example `Create GUID` tool from visual studio and look for format **3** . or look for [example](https://github.com/tpn/winsdk-10/blob/master/Include/10.0.10240.0/km/amtvuids.h) if you have declaration in *h* file but no implementation - all what you need implement this yourself in own *c* file